# s2Member subscription modification button not working in PayPal SandBox mode?

Tags: paypal, wordpress, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

This question is relevant only for those familiar with the WP plugin "s2Member".

I've been trying to allow a "Free Subscriber" (level #0) to modify her subscription to a paying customer (level #1, for example) using a "Subscr Modification Button" carefully following s2Member's instructions.
In particular, I wanted the user's status to be changed due to the checkout in PayPal.

But the PROBLEM was that instead, the user kept on being redirected (after the PayPal process) to REGISTER for a new username for the site!!! The original existing user who started the process remained a "Free Subscriber" (and the new username, btw, would have a "level #1" access if created, but this is NOT what I wanted -- I wanted to MODIFY the existing user).

p.s. I'm using PayPal in SandBox mode, a feature which s2Member claims to support.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is has anyone else experienced this problem?  If so, my answer is "yes."

I just tried following the instructions demonstrated by the [official video tutorial](http://youtu.be/gmfTF1ycsD8) on my local WordPress installation with PayPal in sandbox mode.  I logged in to my local WordPress site as a Level 0 (free) Subscriber and immediately after clicking the "Subscription Modification Button" that I created, I was asked to login to a PayPal sandbox test account.  After logging in and paying to upgrade on my PayPal sandbox store, I was returned to my local WordPress install and greeted with the news that my Level 0 user account was not upgraded and this message which appears to indicate that testing subscription modification in sandbox mode is *not* possible because it requires email confirmation:

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il2m2.png)

I went ahead and notified s2Member support of this predicament to see if they have anything to say on the matter.

Lastly, I think this question would be better suited on [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=s2member).

Comment: I also see that a [thread](http://www.primothemes.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=16723&p=61795#p61795) was already started on the official s2Member forum.